# Github codespaces project live preview not working

Tags: github, nginx, docusaurus, codespaces

I am running a simple project of Docusaurus with `npm start` which runs successfully.

Using Github Codespaces to run the project but the forwarded route doesn't seem to be working.

Attached the screenshots of environment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this? Hitting my head against a wall with the same issue right now.

Answer (score 3):

And, found an answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/6865#issuecomment-1062884672)!

Running `npm run start -- --host 0.0.0.0` works like a charm

Comment: Oh thanks. Sadly my codespaces usage is full and billing thing shows up now so can't test this but hopefully this will work.

Comment: Had the same problem and the host args fixed it. `yarn start --host 0.0.0.0`